# Error in compilation and Linking using CMake with Gcov

Tags: cmake

Im getting the following errors during compilation and linking while using gcov to get coverage information

```
error: undefined reference to '__gcov_merge_add'
error: undefined reference to '__gcov_init'
```

Im passing flags to the CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
```

Do I have to add any thing else to the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Set the compiler flags

```
add_compile_options(-g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage)
```

Link to lgcov

```
target_link_libraries(
    <target-name>
    gcov
)
```

Or use a [CMake module](https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want coverage for Debug builds, your flags should be:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
```

For further info, see http://cmake.org/Wiki/CTest/Coverage and http://cmake.org/Wiki/CTest/Coverage/Example

Comment: Thank you for reply but it did not work. I found another way though. There is line target_link_libraries(gcov) which solves the problem.

Comment: Do not use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` but `add_compile_options` or `target_compile_definitions` instead.